# JSON Data filled with slashes

Tags: javascript, json, csv

Hello im working on a project were i have to update a database filled with JSON data. However this data looks like this:

> {\"Id\":\"1\",\"Sounding\":\"1.075\",\"Ullage\":\"0\",\"Full\":\"100\",\"CapacityM\":\"3.918\",\"CapacityMT\":\"3.918\",\"LCG\":\"3.779\",\"TCG\":\"0\",\"VCG\":\"2.39\",\"FSM\":\"4.492\"}

However if i convert the original data to json format (from CSV file), it appears like this:

> {"ID":1,"SOUNDING":1.075,"ULLAGE":0.000,"FULL":100.000,"CAPACITY":3.918,"CAPACITY":3.918,"LCG":3.779,"TCG":0.000,"VCG":2.390,"FSM
>   ":0.000}

How do i add all those slashes like in the first one so it is the correct format? Do I really need them?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I have a .js file where the data is stored like i posted above (first block). However, I need to update this data with new data i have in a .CSV file. it needs to be in the same format since a program is using it. however if i convert it to JSON it appears as in the second block.

Comment: Can you post sample of your input and how do you convert it to json?

Comment: More importantly, how are you reading the data from the database? You may find that you are just seeing those slashes because thats how visual studio is displaying it to you, when actually they aren't there in memory at all!

Comment: Its hard to post it here but its just columns with data. like columns: ID, SOUNDING, ULLAGE etc. with a list of values on every column.

I use this converter: http://shancarter.com/data_converter/ to convert it to JSON properties

Comment: Have you tried just entering the data as it is? I suspect it may work...

Comment: But I have to edit it in a JS file. The file will change it automaticly if i change it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the string in database is javascript (or C- or Java-, you should check) string escaped. Simplest way to do that is use [org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeEcmaScript%28java.lang.String%29) or [org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29) method. Also check the other methods of these classes.

Alternative would be to store the first JSON as string in 2nd temp JSON object, then convert the 2nd JSON object to string, then get substring containing just the escaped string value of 1st JSON object out of that (I think that would be the part between the 3rd and last double quotes in the 2nd JSON string...). Slightly hacky, but avoids adding extra library.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the data has been escaped for some programming language's string/text literal format.

Answer (score 0):

If I have not misunderstood anything I think you can solve this using [`json_parse`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json_parse.js).

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/yEJdq/

```
json_parse(data, function(key, value) {
    var floatVal = parseFloat(value);
    return !isNaN(floatVal) && isFinite(value) ? floatVal : value;
});
```

It uses json_parse but sends it a delegate which interprets strings that look like numbers as numbers.

EDIT: here is a version which also converts all keys to uppercase (in case you also want that): http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/yEJdq/2/

Comment: Thanks alot but maybe a really stupid question, how would i be able to use this code?

Comment: You need to put the data you receive (the one with all the slashes) in a variable as a string. You can name the variable "data". Then call json_parse function with your data-variable as the first parameter, and the delegate (the function that converts strings to numbers) as the second. Check out the example made for you: http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/yEJdq/